# how to add a row name column into a file in linux?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I Have a huge file (50000 rows) looks like :

input.txt:

```
123315334262625363534
265343426272282827262
224343536625242536363
635352627273635373732
363353533637383838327
635342422325337474524
```

I want to add row numbers as the first column  at the beginning of the file while each number repeated two times:

```
1 123315334262625363534
1 265343426272282827262
2 224343536625242536363
2 635352627273635373732
3 363353533637383838327
3 635342422325337474524
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{getline l; printf "%d %s\n%d %s\n", ++i, $0, i, l}' <in >out
```

Comment: thanks, if I want the row  number do not be repeated then how should I change this? I mean if I want it to be like 1 2 3 ...

Comment: @zara: Just `awk '{print FNR, $0}' <in >out`.

Answer (score 0):

Other **awk**

```
awk '{print ++count, $0}NR%2{count--}' <in >out
```

**sed** + **nl**

```
sed 'N;s/\n/@/' <in |
nl |
sed 's/\(\(^\s*[0-9]*\s*\).*\)@/\1\n\2/' >out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 'printf "%d ", .5+$./2'
```